# There is a way to get all keys of the array?

Tags: php

I want to get all keys of the array an compare each key to number, somthing like that:

```
array(
[0] => 7
[1] => 8
[2] => 4
[3] => 6
)

if (6 != EACH KEY OF ARRAY) {
    so...
}
```

The condition wont show because there is [3] => 6 and the key 6 = 6 of course.

There is a function to do it? somthing else?

Comment: Really now?  You couldn't just google "php array keys"?

Comment: to get list of array key use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php [array_keys] and to iterate through all members of array without knowing keys use http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php [foreach]

Comment: There is all in Google, so why this website exists?
Im begginer so I dont know it well (and I really sorry -_-).

Comment: well, we are happy to help, but that question just doesnt make much sense. Can you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3407967/edit) and be more clear about what you are trying to do or want to achieve?

Comment: You said "...and the key 6 = 6 of course..." BUT your array does not have a key `6`. Maybe you meant: "...and the key 6 != 6 of course..." instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.

```
foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
  if (6 != $key) {
   // so...
  }
}
```

**Example:**

```
$array = array(7, 8, 4, 6);

foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
  if (6 != $key) {
   echo '6 is not equal to ' . $key . '<br />';
  }
  else {
   echo '6 is equal to ' . $key . '<br />';
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
6 is not equal to 7
6 is not equal to 8
6 is not equal to 4
6 is equal to 6
```

If however, you want to check if the ***value*** of 6 is present in the array, use `in_array` like this:

```
if (in_array(6, $array)) {
  // 6 is present in the array
}
```

Comment: if (6 != $key && 6 != $val) {

Comment: Its not good because it will do the condition many times.. I want to pass on the array one time and check all in one time.

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Fosco: OP needs to check keys as he has not specified if value exists, however i have suggested that too.

Comment: Wait, he wanted the value all along? What the heck? >_<

Comment: I think you mean: $key => $val

Comment: @stjowa: Yes but technically `$val` stood for key and vice versa, code works fine but yes i named variables wrongly. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 4):

You want the [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) functions, most likely:

```
<?php
$array = array(7,8,4,6);

// Keys is an array of the keys from $array - [0,1,2,3]
$keys = array_keys($array);

print_r($keys);
?>
```

The output of that print_r would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```

(Note the original keys are the **values** of the new array.)

You then want to check if the value you are looking for is in the array using [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
<?php
echo in_array(6, $keys) // FALSE
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see if a key is present in the array, this is the fastest method:

```
$key = 6; // for example
if(isset($myArray[$key]))
{
    echo "the key $key is used in the array";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!in_array(6)) {
}
```

Yes I know OP asks about keys, but from his example it seems he wants values.

Comment: He is not looking for the value 6, but the key, where `$array[key] = value`

Comment: nope, he's looking for the value... look @ OP's comment on the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking but one of these will probably fit you:

**Get just the keys:**

```
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

---

**Exchanges keys with values:**

```
print_r(array_flip($array));
```

---

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    var_dump($key, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't have more than one of the same key so there is no need to loop through the entire array just write code to look for it.  you could do this:

```
$arr = Array('1'=>'a','3'=>'b','6'=>'c');

if (array_key_exists('6',$arr))
{
    echo 'value of 6 = ' . $arr['6'];
}
```