# How to create a string that contains the keys of a given array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array holding this data:

```
Array ( 
  [1402377] => 7 
  [1562441] => 7 
  [1639491] => 9 
  [1256074] => 10 
 )
```

How can create a string that contains the keys of the above array?
Essentially, I need to create a comma separated string that consists of an array's keys

The string would look like: 'key','key','key'

Do I need to create a new array consisting of the keys from an existing array?

The reason I need to do this is because I will be querying a MySQL database using a `WHERE in ()` statement. I would rather not have to query the database using a foreach statement. Am I approaching this problem correctly?

I've tried using a `while` statement, and I'm able to print the array keys that I need, but I need those keys to be an array in order to send to my model.

The code that allowed me to print the array keys looks like this:

```
while($element = current($array)) {
            $x = key($array)."\n";
            echo $x;
            next($array);
        }
```

Comment: Be careful about [injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) vulnerabilities. Familiarize yourself with the [array functions](http://it.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Splitting an Array into two arrays - keys array and values array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234696/), [MySQL Prepared statements with a variable size variable list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/).

Comment: ...[There is a way to get all keys of the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407967/), [Print the keys of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507381/), [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/), [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = implode(',', array_keys($array));
```

By the way, for looping over an array consider not using current and next but use foreach:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    //do something
}
```

This will automatically iterate over the array until all records have been visited (or not at all if there are no records.

Answer (score 2):

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$string = implode(' ',$keys);
```

In your case, were you are using the result in a `IN` clause you should do:
    $string = implode(',', $keys);

Answer (score 1):

```
$yourString = '';
foreach($yourArr as $key => $val) {
 $yourString .=$key.",";
}
echo rtrim($yourString, ",");

//OR
$yourString = implode(",", array_keys($yourArray));
```

See : [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
implode(', ', array_keys($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) methods

```
print implode(PHP_EOL, array_keys($element))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The string would look like: 'key','key','key'

$string = '\'' . implode('\',\'', array_keys($array)) . '\'';
```

Answer (score 0):

Imploding the arguments and interpolating the result into the query can cause an [injection](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5DP0N1P76E.html) vulnerability. Instead, create a prepared statement by [repeating](http://php.net/str_repeat) a string of parameter placeholders.

```
$paramList = '(' . str_repeat('?, ', count($array) - 1) . '?)'
$args = array_keys($array);
$statement = 'SELECT ... WHERE column IN ' . $paramList;
$query = $db->prepare($statement);
$query->execute($args);
```